# How to make request from Class files(serverside) to .aspx file(clientside)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, .net-2.0

This is different problem for me. I used ASP.NET2.0 with AJAX,C#.

Regularly client make request from HTML (client side) to any class(.cs) file(server side). And then make updation on that class files through Object or in database.

But I want to make request from Class file (server side) to HTML file (client side) based on that Object.

I m also used HashTable for containing Key and  related to that Object.

If you are not able to understand then I try to Explain you my problem differently, I will give you one simple Example :I m calling any function from javascript to my class function, now I want call from class function to javascript function.

please explain me in brief,
Please Help me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean be "aspx file (client side)" - the client doesn't have apsx - only html (etc). And they won't service requests... can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: Since a page renders based on server side logic, it is unclear what else you mean by "request from Class file".

Comment: sorry friends, But I cannot Explain you my problem perfectly, I will give you one simple Example :I m calling any function from javascript to my class function, now I want call from class function to javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually change the contents of an UpdatePanel during a partial page postback. So if the client clicks something on your ASPX page which alters your object on the server-side, you can update the controls on the ASPX page during that round trip.

If you need to simply update your view occasionally with no user interaction, then the [ASP.NET AJAX Timer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) will help.

Comment: you are right but I want different things, Example:- In my database if any changes occurs then it will give response to the client, as per this you can use Classes or namespace  instead of Database.

Comment: Yeah, that is impossible through a browser. There is no way for a server to fire an event on the client. The best workaround to this common problem is to have a timer on the client side that frequently requests updates from the server. The server then keeps track of all the things it needs to send.

Comment: A year later... You can use a Publish/Subscribe service such as PubNub to publish events in your C# server side script then receive them in JavaScript on the client's browser in real time. http://www.pubnub.com/tutorial/csharp-push-api You'd still need your server side to probably do polling of the database to check for changes. Or get a SQL trigger to do a publish to PubNub on changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods for interacting with server side code from the client side:

1. Update panels: This uses a partial postback where the page essentially does a full postback to the server and then ignores everything except whats in the update panel then sends the result back.
2. Page methods - This might not be quite what you are looking for since page methods require that the method be static on the page itself.
3. Web service methods - These are the same web services you may use from your aspx code behind but you will need a script manager on the page to use them from javascript.